# FirstOrDefault unexpected result when mixed with null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, null-coalescing-operator

I've got a scenario where I need to query an object and if null is returned, then I need to query the same object differently, I decided to use the null-coalescing operator, here's the code:

```
 var requestedMaterials = request.Lines.FirstOrDefault(
                          w => w.Description.Trim() == material.Description.Trim() &&
                          w.Grade.Grades.Any(q => q.Quantity > 0)) ??
                          request.Lines.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Description.Trim() ==  material.Description.Trim() && w.Quantity > 0)
```

The left hand operand is expected to return null, the right hand is not, in fact, if I set it to a variable I can see its not null, but for some reason, when I use both queries this way, requestMaterials is null, instead of having the value of the right hand operand.

I've confirmed that, when I set these two queries to variables and use the '??' operator on them, it works as expected, I've left it this way for now, but I'm really curious why It didn't work the other way.

The working example (requestedMaterials is filled up with the materialsWithoutGrade):

```
var materialsWithGrade = request.Lines.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Description.Trim() == material.Description.Trim() &&  w.Grade.Grades.Any(q => q.Quantity> 0));
var materialsWithoutGrade = request.Lines.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Description.Trim() == material.Description.Trim() && w.Quantity> 0);

var requestedMaterials = materialsWithGrade ?? materialsWithoutGrade;
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you receive an error?

Comment: @twrowsell: nope, requestedMaterials is null, and it should have the value of the right hand operand, I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: so you've ran request.Lines.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Description.Trim() ==  material.Description.Trim() && w.Quantity > 0) and it returns a non null reference?

Comment: One spot, try with the ternary operator. Just curious.

Comment: twrowsell: yes, I ran it and set it to a variable, it has value, but when I use it the way I've shown, the target variable (requestedMaterials) is null

Comment: I think it could be very interesting to see the generated SQL when everything is inlined with the `??` operator. Can you attach a SQL Profiler or use LinqPad?

Comment: Don't know if it's Linq2sql, if yes please correct the tags.

Comment: Is this the *full* code to reproduce? If this is a part of another query or a part of it was left out then I could see some scenarios where this would happen. Can you post the code you used to debug when you set each query to a variable?

Comment: @Lucian/Teejay: It's Linq-To-Objects, I'm sorry, fixed the tag.

Comment: @Ocelot20: The full code is quite lengthy cause I haven't refactor yet, this code is placed inside a foreach loop, thats where 'material' variable come from. Though I'll edit the question and add the variables to show a working example.

Comment: You should try to create a [short but complete example](http://sscce.org/). (I'm sure you'll find that the `??` operator isn't buggy; you may find the answer yourself, or the example might let us help you)

Comment: @BrenoSarkis `for each` makes me think some kind of deferring is happening. Try assigning `material` to a variable inside the loop, just before the code you posted, and then use the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

The FirstOrDefault returns either a value if match found, else returns default(TSource) . The ?? was returned default(TSource) which can be anything (null or a default value for the type TSource). After you assign the result to a variable, now variable holds a null value. so ?? is able to work as expected now.